# Time In and Time Out of night shift employees

Tags: java, db2

I have table of structure

### BADGE_NO / LOG_TIME

E001  /   2012-12-28 09:56:23

E001  /   2012-12-29 07:58:53

Employee with badge no E001 comes for a night shift which is from 10.00 pm to 08.00 am.
How can i determine the time in and time out of that employee on a particular date ?
I use java and db2.

Comment: @ Marco : MIN and Max functions of db2

Comment: E001 came in at 10pm on 28 Dec 2012 and left at 8am on 29 Dec 2012.  Determining which of the two dates E001 worked is the work date is arbitrary and up to your company and local labor laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i determine the time in and time out of that employee on a particular date?

E001 came in at 10pm on 28 Dec 2012 and left at 8am on 29 Dec 2012, approximately.

One way to look at it is that E001 worked 2 hours on 28 Dec 2012, and 8 hours on 29 Dec 2012.

As I said in the comment, determining the work date is arbitrary.  It's up to your company guided by local labor laws.